Disk usage wrong after incorrect fstab mount and rsync to the mount
tl,dr;
Something is using disk space after failed mount and rsync but I can't find out what it is and how to cleanup/free the space.

Context: I was trying to add second disk to my RPi and given that I didn't have much experience it seems I mount it very incorrectly. And then I ran rsync to move data there but it failed with:
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(848) [sender=3.2.7]
rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1613) [generator=3.2.7]

I was baffled, started checking things out and indeed noticed that lsblk showed my main partition as 96% full and other disk usage was not shown in the output not included in df:
$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL          UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
└─sda1 ext4   1.0   malinkaExtData d06a4ac8-2c34-46e1-9a84-254aac4af784
sdb
├─sdb1 vfat   FAT32 boot           29F5-65C4                               223M    13% /boot
└─sdb2 ext4   1.0   rootfs         cbe4d267-24de-4402-9a4b-1413a1da5eb8     45M    96% /

What I've done:

attached new drive (had to format it to remove efi system partition) and it looked good:

Disk /dev/sda: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SD620
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AAA86F6D-E3AC-4954-8EF8-7B8ABC36970F

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G Linux filesystem

…
Disk /dev/sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: SD600Q
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcded71d7

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      8192    532479    524288   256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       532480 468862127 468329648 223.3G 83 Linux

My initial mount looked like this:
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=cded71d7-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=cded71d7-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
PARTUUID=AAA86F6D-E3AC-4954-8EF8-7B8ABC36970F-01 /mnt/extMalinka               ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail  0       0

I used disk identifier + partition index (akin to sdb). It mounted OK (was able to write to it and checked that after restart files were there) but it seems that it was mounting something on the main drive hence leading to filling up of /dev/sdb2.
While trying to figure out why output of df is not complete I found that one should use blkid command and indeed it showed correct PARTUUID:
$ blkid
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="cbe4d267-24de-4402-9a4b-1413a1da5eb8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cded71d7-02"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="29F5-65C4" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="cded71d7-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="malinkaExtData" UUID="d06a4ac8-2c34-46e1-9a84-254aac4af784" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c26648b6-5140-49c2-9fc2-db1e24f895aa"

I updated /etc/fstab and everything started to work correctly, disk was included in du but the problem was main disk usage. df showed it's almost full:
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       220G  211G   29M 100% /

but du showed more correct value of ~180G (I had 30G free before doing any changes):
$ sudo du -hs /
du: cannot read directory '/proc/4855/task/4855/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/4855/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access '/proc/228792/task/228792/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/228792/task/228792/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/228792/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/228792/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
180G    /


So it seems there is a thing called overlay mount… After doing sudo umount /mnt/extMalinka I saw previous contents (including ~37G of rsync!) and du showed correct usage. So I deleted everything from /mnt/extMalinka, remounted it and the usage reported by du and df went back to normal…
